# How Can I Parse a Document and Replace the Content to Change Context from 1st or 2nd Person to 3rd Person?

Tags: regex, parsing, nlp

Basically I need some text like:

- I have an ice cream cone.
- You are in trouble.
- You need a bath.

And change it from 1st or 2nd person to 3rd person.

- He has an ice cream cone.
- He is in trouble.
- He needs a bath.

I've started a js app, but it's super simple at the moment.

Before I waste time reinventing the wheel, I figured I'd ask: Is anyone aware of any 3rd party libraries that do this sort of thing? If not, does anyone have any advice or guidance to offer to help me get something going?

Comment: Luckily enough you have to do it in English of which conjugation is rather simple. But you will have difficulties managing complements. “I take my car” => “He takes my car” or “his car”?

Comment: The way these documents are written, there will never be a case where the output should be "He takes my car"; It would always be "He takes his car". Still it would be nice to account for any possible scenarios. Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any libraries that do this out-of-the-box, but I've used [Nodebox Linguistics](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics), which has a verb conjugation module, to implement some of this functionality myself. To expand on Benoit's comment, English verb conjugation is *mostly* simple, but there are a lot of nuanced exceptions, especially when changing tense.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll have a look at Nodebox Linguistics and see if it can be used for my needs. I appreciate it!